# How to validate check boxes in a custom dialog? 

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to make a custom dialog with a set of check boxes, and I want to validate them so that if the user clicks the ok button without selecting any one of them, a message will be displayed to the user asking them to select at least one choice. If they have (selected a t least one choice) a message will displayed saying which check boxes that the user has checked.

I can't continue the validation, can anybody help me and does anybody have any ideas about what I should do to validate the check boxes in a custom dialog?

```
Button conditions_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.conditions_btn);
conditions_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Dialog ConditionsDialog =new Dialog(ProfileView.this);
        ConditionsDialog.setContentView(R.layout.diseases);
        ConditionsDialog.setTitle(" select  your health condition   ");

        DCB1=((CheckBox) ConditionsDialog.findViewById(R.id.CB1));
        DCB2=((CheckBox) ConditionsDialog.findViewById(R.id.CB2));
        DCB3=((CheckBox) ConditionsDialog.findViewById(R.id.CB3));
        DCB4=((CheckBox) ConditionsDialog.findViewById(R.id.CB4));

        Diseses_ok_btn= ((Button) ConditionsDialog.findViewById(R.id.ok_button));
        Diseses_ok_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //validate the check boxes  
                if(  DCB1.isChecked()== false&&DCB2.isChecked()==false&&DCB3.isChecked()==false&&DCB4.isChecked()==false ) {
                    showMessage("  please select  your health condition ");
                } else {    
                // what should i do here to get the check boxes that have been checked ??
                }
            }
        });

        Diseses_cancel_btn=((Button)ConditionsDialog..findViewById(R.id.cancel_button));
        Diseses_cancel_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ConditionsDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        ConditionsDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: please add more tags (including programming language)

Comment: i have been searched  over the net but i didnt found the sol for my question  please any body can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am probably misunderstanding your question, but here goes...

I don't know how to access the *names* of your diseases, but I would do something similar this in your 'validation block':

```
String msg = "You have selected:";
if (DCB1.isChecked()) {
    msg += "\n    DCB1"; //or get the disease name
}
if (DCB2.isChecked()) {
    msg += "\n    DCB2"; //or get the disease name
}
if (DCB3.isChecked()) {
    msg += "\n    DCB3"; //or get the disease name
}
if (DCB4.isChecked()) {
    msg += "\n    DCB4"; //or get the disease name
}
showMessage(msg);
```

Comment: you have understood my question. thank you very much for helping me